# Docker. Create image based on MySQL with DB and User created

Tags: mysql, docker

I want to create an image with docker for my app.
The app uses MySQL. I need my image to be based on MySQL image (mysql/mysql-server ?) .
IN the Dockerfile i need to set some instructions to create a DB with specific user/password . So, my app can work with that DB .
I don't need tables, only empty DB with specific name and user/password that can access this DB.

How can i do this?

I wanted something like

```
FROM mysql/mysql-server
# Create MySQL DB
mysql -u root -e "CREATE DATABASE MyDB"
```

But i don't know root user password here. It seems it is autogenerated ?

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That image auto-generates the root password by default, as stated in the image github repository (https://github.com/mysql/mysql-docker). You can set the MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD environment variable in your Dockerfile with the password you want.

Apart from that, if what you want is to create a database at image startup, you can use the environment variable MYSQL_DATABASE.

More info about the supported environment variables here:
https://github.com/mysql/mysql-docker#docker-environment-variables

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 solutions here:

1. [Easy] Using the `docker-compose` and create a `docker-compose.yml` file like this one:

   ```
   version: '3'
   services:
       mariadb:
           container_name: mariadb
           image: mariadb:latest
           environment:
             - MYSQL_DATABASE=_YOUR_DB_
             - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD="_YOUR_PASSWORD_"
             - MYSQL_USER=_YOUR_USER_
             - MYSQL_PASSWORD=_YOUR_USER_PASSWORD_
       ...
   ```

This configuration will bring a `MariaDB` database to you. also if you want to use it, you can simply check this page for the installation guide:
https://github.com/docker/compose

The final step is just to go into the directory you saved the `docker-compose.yml` and just run:

```
docker-compose up
```

or if you don't want to see the log inside the terminal just add `-d` flag to it.
2. [Little Complicated] You can create a custom image for your needs. in this case, it is better if you check the `Dockerfile` documents and then see this autogenerated default MariaDB Dockerfile for understanding what to do exactly to achieve your goal.